# PHP Objects and functions difficulty

Tags: php, web

I am having trouble with objects/classes working with functions in php. This program should echo "New book created" twice for both books but it just has a blank page. In visual studio code the "construct" text is not coloured but white. Whatever suggestions you do enter please make sure it is easy to understand and follow as I'm not a programmer (yet), I'm just following freecodecamp's course - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK_JCtrrv-c ( timestamp - 3:58:36)

This is the code:

```
<?php 

class Book {
    var $title;
    var $author;
    var $pages;
}

function _construct(){
    echo "New Book Created <br>";
}



$book1 = new Book();
$book1 ->title = "Harry Potter";
$book1 ->author = "JK Rowling";
$book1 ->pages = 400;

$book2 = new Book();
$book2 ->title = "Lord of the Rings";
$book2 ->author = "Tolkien";
$book2 ->pages = 700;


?>
```

I was expecting "new book created" to be printed twice.

Comment: You dont even call "_construct" how/why should it output something?! Your `_construct` has absolutly nothing to do with your class. Go and view the video/timestamp closely. Im sure you find your problem...

Comment: `_construct` should have two underscores at the start. This is a [special function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and has to be named exactly in order for that feature to work.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thats not the only issue, op has to move the function.

Comment: Ah yeah, that too.

Comment: The video is correct on both issues, so it's just two typos for OP.

Comment: Yup. OP posted even the solution to the problem he/she is facing :D

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. `__contruct` has two underscores at the start.
2. The constructor needs to be part of the class.

```php
class Book {

  public $title;
  public $author;
  public $pages;

  function __construct(){
    echo "New Book Created <br>";
  }
}
```